# Android Studio Share button

Tags: android, navigation, share, drawer

I wanted to make a share button on a Navigation drawer, when the user touches the button it will open up that black drawer with the list of all applications and the user can share the apps Google play link. Is there any generic code template? the only answers I have found is to just share it on one application such as Facebook which seems useless because not everyone uses Facebook.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use share intent http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

sample code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can send content by invoking an implicit intent with ACTION_SEND.

To send images or binary data:

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

send an image along with text. This can be done with:

```
String text = "Look at my awesome picture";
Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("file://my_picture");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

Sharing multiple images can be done with:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Kotlin version

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
    type = "text/plain"
}

val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```